# Help TOm to find the number of black, white and green pieces?

Tags: geometry, polygons

TOm has a spongy boom ball that is made of 32 pieces of polygon figures: 12 black pentagons and 20 white hexagons. Each pentagon adjoins 5 hexagons and each hexagon adjoins 3 pentagons and 3 hexagons. Boogy drew a polygon (i.e. a closed line without intersections) along the edges of the pieces. The polygon divided the ball into two parts and Boogy painted one of them green. He is curious if given a description of the polygon you are able to compute the number of black, white and green pieces?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly not, because if the polygon cuts the ball into two pieces of different sizes, the answer depends on which piece was painted green - the polygon is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the two parts are equivalent then presumably

- half the original black pentagons are still black $(\frac{12}{2}=6)$;
- half the original white hexagons are still white $(\frac{20}{2}=10)$; and
- half the original polygons are now green $(\frac{32}{2}=16)$.

Otherwise you would have to give a description of the dividing polygon.

Comment: lets take a example
 the first line  contains one integer n being the number of vertices of the polygon. The second line  contains n integers a1, a2,..., an separated by single spaces. Integer ai (equal 1 or 2) is the number of green pieces adjoining the i-th vertex of the polygon. The side of the polygon connecting the n-th and the first vertex always lies between two hexagons.

Comment: example      21 then 21 numbers follow 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1

Comment: answer is 11 15 6 i.e the numbers of black, white and green pieces respectively.